# Swing - Updating element in JList after modifing it in another frame

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code

```
DefaultListModel<String> modelPacientes = new DefaultListModel<>();
JList <String> listPacientes = new JList<>( modelPacientes );
listPacientes.setToolTipText("Lista de los pacientes del doctor");
GridBagConstraints gbc_listPacientes = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_listPacientes.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc_listPacientes.gridx = 0;
gbc_listPacientes.gridy = 0;
pPacientes.add(listPacientes, gbc_listPacientes);
modelPacientes.addElement(raul.getName() + " " + raul.getSurname());
modelPacientes.addElement(paula.getName() + " " + paula.getSurname());
modelPacientes.addElement(sara.getName() + " " + sara.getSurname());
```

I am modifying the values of the objects (raul, paula and sara) in another frame, how could I update it in the JList or anywhere else (JLabel) after closing the other frame?

Comment: 1) *"..in another frame"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am modifying the values of the objects

Then the `ListModel` should contain the Objects not a String. So assuming your Objects are of type `User` you would do something like:

```
DefaultListModel<User> modelPacientes = new DefaultListModel<User>();
JList<User> listPacientes = new JList<User>( modelPacientes );

modelPacientes.addElement(raul);
modelPacientes.addElement(paula);
modelPacientes.addElement(sara);
```

Then in the User class you can override the `toString()` method to return the value you want to display in the `JList`:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return getName() + " " + getSurname();
}
```

> I am modifying the values of the objects (raul, paula and sara) in another frame

Then you get the `User` object you want to modify from the `ListModel` and pass this object to your JDialog (note you should be using a JDialog, not a JFrame for a popup child window).

Then you update the data in the User object and when the dialog closes you invoke `repaint()` on the `JList`.

Answer (score 2):

You can either provide your own subclass of ListModel (or DefaultListModel) that returns `patient.getName() + " " + patient.getSurname())` in method `getElementAt`

or you can move the creation of the `modelPacientes` to a new method:

```
ListModel createModel() {
  DefaultListModel<String> modelPacientes = new DefaultListModel<>();
  modelPacientes.addElement(raul.getName() + " " + raul.getSurname());
  modelPacientes.addElement(paula.getName() + " " + paula.getSurname());
  modelPacientes.addElement(sara.getName() + " " + sara.getSurname());
  return modelPacientes;
}
```

then build an empty `JList` instead and run `listPacientes.setModel(createModel())` whenever the pacientes have changed.

This approach is fine if you have a couple dozens patients.
If you have hundreds or thousands of patients, it is probably worthwhile to you have your own model classes that map from your patient data into whatever the Swing component needs.

Answer (score 0):

Add the objects (`raul`, `paula` and `sara`) to the list modal.  Then create a [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) that will return a string that is the "display name" for example:

```
raul.getName() + " " + raul.getSurname()
```

That way when the name of `raul`, `paula` and/or `sara` changes it will automatically change in the list if it is the same instance of the object.